# Set alpha to a custom style for dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, alpha

I have a custom dialog created and and I want to apply a custom theme to it. 
So I created a style in the following way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="dialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:background">#222</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

this changed the background of my dialog. What I am looking for is to set an alpha to this background. I don't know how to do it.

If I change the parent as Theme.dialog, I get what I want in respect to the background but in addition I also get a border to my custom dialog which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Android Colors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

You can give the alpha value in the hex code.

opaque-black would be 0xFF000000 (100% opaque but no contributions from red, green, or blue), and opaque-white would be 0xFFFFFFFF

Notice the first two values give the alpha value.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in code by choosing the color and setting its opaquecity as follow:

```
ColorDrawable dialogColor = new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY);
dialogColor.setAlpha(100);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(dialogColor);
```

Comment: I got your solution.This is the simplest way to set the background 50% transparent